# Profiling Go web application built with Gorilla's mux with net/http/pprof

Tags: go

I have a relatively big web application written in Go that uses [Gorilla's mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) for routing.  I recently realised that my web application is quite slow and I would like to profile the web application.

After reading about it, it seems that [net/http/pprof](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) is what I need.  But I can't make it run with *mux*; even in the case of the most trivial web application.

Does anyone knows how to make that work?

Here is an example of a trivial code that does not work (i.e. nothing is served at `/debug`).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "math"
    "net/http"
)
import _ "net/http/pprof"

func SayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        math.Pow(36, 89)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello!")
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/hello", SayHello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":6060", r)
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry for that question.  The answer is in the init() function of [pprof](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/).  One just need to add 4 functions from `pprof` to the mux router.  Here is the fixed code from above.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "math"

    "net/http"
)
import "net/http/pprof"

func AttachProfiler(router *mux.Router) {
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/", pprof.Index)
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/cmdline", pprof.Cmdline)
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/profile", pprof.Profile)
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/symbol", pprof.Symbol)
}

func SayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        math.Pow(36, 89)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello!")
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    AttachProfiler(r)
    r.HandleFunc("/hello", SayHello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":6060", r)
}
```

Answer (score 36):

My preferred method for this is to just let `net/http/pprof` register itself to `http.DefaultServeMux`, and then pass all requests starting with `/debug/pprof/` along:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.PathPrefix("/debug/pprof/").Handler(http.DefaultServeMux)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":6060", router); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I find that this approach is a lot more stable than one that depends on the implementation of a hidden initialization method, and also guarantees that you didn't miss anything.

Comment: We should be aware that `/debug/pprof/` route should not be exposed publicly in production as it may expose sensitive data.

See the suggestion in the following article where the default mux routes are disabled and you only expose the pprof for localhost access: https://docs.boostsecurity.io/rules/code-debugging-interface-publicly-exposed.html

Answer (score 34):

user983716 - Thanks for your question and solution!

I was not able to use the links from the web index (http://[my-server]/debug/pprof), until I added a few lines to your solution, like so:

```
...

func AttachProfiler(router *mux.Router) {
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/", pprof.Index)
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/cmdline", pprof.Cmdline)
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/profile", pprof.Profile)
    router.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/symbol", pprof.Symbol)

    // Manually add support for paths linked to by index page at /debug/pprof/
    router.Handle("/debug/pprof/goroutine", pprof.Handler("goroutine"))
    router.Handle("/debug/pprof/heap", pprof.Handler("heap"))
    router.Handle("/debug/pprof/threadcreate", pprof.Handler("threadcreate"))
    router.Handle("/debug/pprof/block", pprof.Handler("block"))
}

...
```

If anyone has the same problem, I hope this helps!

Comment: I just did `router.PathPrefix("/debug/pprof/").HandlerFunc(pprof.Index)` which covers everything not explicitly routed.

Answer (score 7):

I did something else, I added another native http server on a different port and it just works out of the box

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    _ "net/http/pprof"
)


func main() {
    go func() {
        log.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil))
    }()
    log.Fatalln(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", route.Handlers()))
}
```

Now the pprof endpoint is at :
    http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/ and the applcation is running on port :8080

Answer (score 5):

Previous examples not really work on my side.

To use pprof in an existing golang project with gorrila/mux, try to add :

```
...previous code

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/hello", SayHello)

    go func() {
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":6061", http.DefaultServeMux))
    }()

    http.ListenAndServe(":6060", r)
}
```

then go to http://localhost:6061/debug/pprof/

Answer (score 2):

Just so:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.PathPrefix("/debug").Handler(http.DefaultServeMux)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter but i just got this answer from google search.
That's what i did

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.Handler("GET", "/debug/pprof/profile", http.DefaultServeMux)
router.Handler("GET", "/debug/pprof/heap", http.DefaultServeMux)
```

I only need this two routes.
This answer is combine of @damien and @user983716 answers.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
import (
 "net/http"
 _ "net/http/pprof"
)

myrouter.PathPrefix("/debug/pprof/").Handler(http.DefaultServeMux)
```